# Return data from multiple tables in a gridview on a single button click

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

There are five tables. My question is how to perform search on one table and move to another table if the result is not there, and display relevant information where ever it's found, in a gridview, on my .aspx page. The problem is I have to implement this search using a single button click event (Cannot use radiobuttons or checkboxes to filter).

Comment: share your code and table structures.

Comment: Share some code, or at least the table structure.

Comment: what do you mean Excatly ??? you can use Views .. share more information